# Let $R$ be the ring of functions $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Then $X^2-X$ has infinitely many roots.

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R$ be the ring of functions $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Prove that the polynomial $X^2-X\in R[X]$ has infinitely many roots.

Am I supposed to show that there are infinitely many $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n^2-n\equiv 0\pmod 2$? Or am I misinterpreting this question?

Comment: You have to show there are infinitely many $f \in R$ such that $f^2 - f = 0$. That is, you have to show there are infinitely many functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n)^2 - f(n) = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll work on that and post my answer

Comment: Is it wrong to say "$f(n)=n+k\pmod 2$ for all $k\in \Bbb{Z}$"? Would all of these functions be considered distinct? Or in the same vein: $f(n)=nk\pmod 2$ for ever-increasing $k$?

Comment: @PatrickShambayati All of those for $k$ even are the same function, as they are the same for $k$ odd. Try to show that every $f\in R$ satisfies $X^2-X=0$. To show that $R$ is infinite just consider the functions $f_n(k)=0$ for $k\neq n$ and $f_n(n)=1$.

Comment: How about the trivial polynomials $f(n)=2n$ in $\mathbb R[X]$ ?

Comment: Oh I see. For any $f\in R$, $f(n)=0$ or $f(n)=1$. If $f(n)=0$ then $(f^2-f)(n)=0$. If $f(n)=1$ then $(f^2-f)(n)=1-1=0$. Does that prove that every $f$ satisfies $X^2-X=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the operations in $R$ are defined *pointwise*, based on the standard operations in the field $\Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z$, that is, for two maps $f, g: \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$ we take $(f + g)(n) = f(n) + g(n)$ and $(fg)(n) = f(n)g(n)$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.  Then for any such $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$, we must have

$(f(n))^2 = f(n), \tag{1}$

since for each $n \in \Bbb N$ we have $f(n) = 0$ or $f(n) = 1$.  This shows that *every* $f \in R$ is a zero of the polynomial $X^2 - X$.

$X^2 - X \in R[X]$ has a *lot* of roots.  Indeed, in appears that such functions are in one-to-one correspondence with $2^{\Bbb N}$, the power set of $\Bbb N$.  For any subset $\Bbb M \subset \Bbb N$, we may define $f_{\Bbb M}$ to be the charactersitic function of $\Bbb M$:

$f_{\Bbb M}(n) = 1 \Leftrightarrow n \in \Bbb M; \tag{2}$

likewise, given $f \in R$, taking $\Bbb M_f$ to be the set

$\Bbb M_f = \{ n \in \Bbb N \mid f(n) = 1 \} \tag{3}$

we see that

$f_{\Bbb M_f} = f \tag{4}$

and

$\Bbb M_{f_{\Bbb M}} = M. \tag{5}$

It is as if the value of $f(n)$ can be taken as a "yes" or "no" to the question, "Is $n \in \Bbb M_f \subset \Bbb N$?"

Contrast this to the case in which $R$ is a field.  Then $X^2 - X$ has exactly two zeroes.

Comment: Thanks! I checked out your profile--you're a chill dude!

Comment: @Patrick Shambayati:  Hey!  Thanks for the kind words, and for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!